# If one expresses a function as a linear combination of other functions, can the linear combination relationship be inverted?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

If one has a function say f, that can be expressed as a linear combination of another type of function say g, can one **invert** the relationship as a linear combination of the other function? i.e. if one has:

$$ f(x) = \sum^{N}_{n=1} c_ng(ax - n)$$

can one always find a linear combination of $g$ using only functions $f$ as in:

$$ g(x) = \sum^{N}_{n'=1} c'_n f(a'x - n')$$

The reason I thought this might be possible was because of the intuition that functions can be expressed as vectors. This is true, if one vector can be expressed as a linear combination of independent vectors then one can find an inverse mapping always. Right? The issue I am having is that I am not an expert in functional analysis type of things so I wasn't sure if this argument was right (or the caveats in infinite dimensional spaces/vectors), though I suspect that its approximately correct in similar conditions, though I didn't know how to make it rigorous.

If there are cases when its true, it be nice if its explained why its true in that case and when its false, apart from providing a counter example(s) it'd be nice to provide insight/intuition on why it was not suppose to work.

Comment: As it stands, no. Consider $n=1$: if $f(x)=g(x-1)$ then $g(x)$ is hardly a multiple of $f(a'x-1)$ in general (as it is rather $f(x+1)$)